# How to wait for a process in Java

Tags: java

In the following code, I tried to execute a script, which takes quite a while to finish.So, I already tried to use `process.waitfor()` but it didn't let the script finish. Are there any ideas how to make it work?

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(osShell);
Process process = pb.start();
PrintWriter pyCon = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
pyCon.println("cd " + videoDir);
System.out.println("Executing python file: "+ command);
pyCon.println(command);
//Here, I need a piece of code which let's my command run in peace              
pyCon.close();

System.out.println(convertStreamToString(process.getInputStream()));
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By closing the stdin of the shell process, you pretty much told it it's over. Chances are the shell ended killing the child python cmd, or at least not draining nor forwarding the python stdout/stderr to its own shell stdout/stderr.

Try waiting for some expected end marker from your python cmd. Then only close stdin. Drain all the stdout/stderr from the process of course.

It common to see 2 more threads just to pump out the bytes from stdout/stderr while the main thread is controlling/waiting for the process. Keep in mind that if you don't pump the bytes out, the pipes may fill up and block on the child side, preventing it from terminating. These pipes are often pretty small (512 to 2k bytes for instance - that is obviously testable).

Comment: Since I am new to this, could you elaborate how to do it since one can't flush an inputstream. Thank you very much :)

Comment: stdin of the child process is an output stream from the point of view of the parent, so the process stdin (pyCon) can be flushed without being closed just yet. As for the rest (pumping bytes out with threads), I usually don't provide code on SO, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sending commands to a shell’s standard input is unlikely to work, especially in Windows.

The correct way to execute something in a particular directory is not by trying to send a `cd` command, but by [specifying the directory in the ProcessBuilder itself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", pythonFileName);
pb.directory(new File(videoDir));
Process process = pb.start();
```

Comment: It's correct, but possibly not sufficient; we don't know what the user is trying to do; perhaps he needs to run different commands in different folders within one shell (which could easily be a bash on windows, btw).